# Universal Analytics Syntax Error

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am trying to get Universal Analytics up and running and I am running into an issue. When I put in the code:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

I keep getting a syntax error

[image]

Is anyone else having this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: Is that the entire code snippet? Is it wrapped in a script tag?

Comment: In the error message there is a comma where a curled bracket should be. That does not usually happen - if you have actually pasted to correct tracking code then some weird process in your website changes the source code (which sounds unlikely, so check your source again).

Comment: Checked my source, copied the code straight from google, still getting the same error

Comment: Can you post the code output on your site? As @EikePierstorff mentioned you're missing part of the code.

Comment: Thanks Eike I was able to figure it out thanks to your comment!